# Am I breaking MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

This question is mostly for my own curiosity, as I understand architecture patterns are there to help us, not control us, but I'm curious to know if the way I've structured this small pet project is a proper implementation of the MVC architecture.

I'm used to developing in the browser for web applications, where the browser acts as a sort of "master controller" (you click a link, it will change views for me, without having to code anything extra). However I'm working on a desktop application for this pet project, and I'm curious how to implement the "browser", if you will. I've looked back at some Flash project I've worked on, and I noticed they had the code for handling the view creations in the root class for the project. Does this make sense? Another thought I had was to create a "ViewPort" class or something that basically took that that functionality out of the root class, and basically acted as a combination view/controller (or I can even make a controller class to go along with it) and have that class change between all the views I need to navigate through. But I also wasn't sure if that made sense.

Is there a standard way to manage your views in the MVC? Do you use a controller for the root window which then displays your different views (which also have controllers of their own?) Like I said, this is more for my own curiosity, so I appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a controller for the root window in MVC if I'm understanding your comparison properly.

So in the case where you have a shared layout page, you have a view that will automatically load for every view that uses this _layout.cshtml file.

Now if you have for instance a customer order window you could have all of this
1. the layout.cshtml file for the overall shared look and feel of your site
2. the main view say /MySite/CustomerOrder/Index/656  - the contents created by your CustomerController.cs file, a method named Index.
3. On your /Views/CustomerOrder/Index.cshtml view, you can then call off to show other views
RenderAction("Index", "CustomerOrderHistory", new {customerId=@Model.CustomerId}
That goes through a controller named CustomerOrderHistoryController.cs and looks for a method named Index
or 
RenderPartial("CustomerHistory") 
That goes directly to a view and copied and sends over the current view's model to it.

So to answer your question, you can have a main view with other views in it.. but it depends if you want to do it this way - you dont have to.

Answer (score 0):

Passive View or Supervising controller are better fits for winforms applications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx